# I'm building an app that requires Data Integration with customer's database

Tags: database, database-connection

I'm in the process of designing an application that would tie into the database for multiple e-commerce stores.

I have the general business logic down but the problem is, I have no idea on the most painfree and effective way to do the data integration.  I know how to access my own databases, but this is something I always just left to my hosting provider to handle the backend and I just developed the interface

Can someone point me in the right direction on this? There is a large emphasis on ease of installation.  So my customers (once I get them) should be able to very easily integrate their system into my app.

Comment: Tie to database or to web site?  They're different.  The web site is public and on port 80 and you already have access to it, trivially.  The database, however isn't public.  The title says web site.  The question body says database.  The tags say database.  Which is right?

Answer (score 1):

RESTful web services are what many folks do for this.

Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Then revise this to be a more specific question.

You might need to look at direct VPN/SSL connection from their server to yours.

Comment: Hi. S.Lott.
I've revised the question title to indicAte that I need to access their database.

Does REST still apply in this case?

Comment: @DevX: Yes.  However, you have to install RESTful web services on their servers to get access to their database.